# ordering by date in nested loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i have a nested foreach loop within a while loop. i extract from a myqsl text field dates that match a range. the only problem is that i can't order by date after having extracted the text field. if i have the same date (02.01.2013 in this example) into two different text fields it would appear in the output as:

```
       TOUR 1  
       01.01.2013
    -> 02.01.2013 
    -> 03.01.2013
       04.01.2013

       TOUR 2
    -> 02.01.2013 
    -> 03.01.2013
```

i can't figure out how to group by date ($day) after the loop. i know the solution would be to create an array for this but how ?

here's my code:

```
     $sql = "SELECT accommodation, start FROM circuits_".$_POST['year']." 
     WHERE start >='".$first."' AND start <= '".$last."' 
     ORDER BY start";
     $rows = $db->query($sql);

     while ($record = $db->fetch($rows)) { 

     $data_acc = explode(';',$record['accommodation'], -1);

     foreach($data_acc as $row_acc) {
     list($day,$name,$sgl,$dbl) = explode('|',$row_acc);
```

thanx

Comment: Don't `circuits_".$_POST['year']." `!!! This is a very unsecure approach.

Comment: this is an intranet not public website. and my mysql class escape strings automatically

Comment: @svartbakur - It doesn't matter if your site is on intranet or internet. You should always take security in consideration. It ain't secure from threats just because the system is "inside of the company". '(Employees, visitors etc, etc may be able to do stupid things...)

Comment: Answer to your question: Use GROUP BY 'date column' in your sql?

Comment: Is that list of dates coming from your exploded '$day' field?

Comment: @phatfingers yes the list comes from the exploded $day field so any order or group in the mysql query won't affect the order.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld as i said my class is escaping the query. it's not because you don't see it that it's not

Comment: @svartbakur - I think you're complicating things a lot. Do the grouping in the query instead of trying to do it with php-code. With the php-code you just loop through the resultset of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this?
(Replace `ORDER BY` with `GROUP BY`)

```
$sql = "SELECT accommodation, start FROM circuits_".$_POST['year']." 
 WHERE start >='".$first."' AND start <= '".$last."' 
 GROUP BY start";
 $rows = $db->query($sql);

 while ($record = $db->fetch($rows)) { 
    //do whatever..
 }
```

Comment: GROUPING in the query will only affect each exploded list. Even with a GROUO BY i obtain the same result.

Comment: @svartbakur - Ok, what exactly do you want to achieve with your code? (all code that relates your question) I would really want some clarification here (maybe you could edit your question?)

Answer (score 0):

Your development would be less complicated if you split your data into fields before storing them in the database.

Without changing your current schema, you could use uksort() to post-process your array.  Using uksort will allow you to parse the dates before comparing them.  Or possibly, you could convert each date to ISO-8601 before storing it in your list and use the simpler ksort().

Comment: i have a large amount of data so concatenating was the way to go. it's harder to manipulate i know. the date is stored as unix stamp. you see the date format after transformation. i could use ksort for this. but it will affect each loop from the mysql query and would have still the same problem.

Comment: can you add a timestamp column to your table?

Comment: hello phatfingers. i have a start and end column that are timestamp already. i explain better. this table contain info of tours with beginning and ending date. my requests extract a text field with dates and names of hotels. the code as it is will display the result, no matter what i do, by tour name, because of the foreach loop within my while loop. using sort function will just order the result within the tour. i hope i'm clear !

Comment: i edited my question so you can view that the request is grouped by tour. and what i need is to have the same dates either close to each other or having a grouped by similar date.

Comment: It looks to me like you're wanting to `ORDER BY SUBSTRING(accommodation,7,4)||LEFT(accommodation,5)`.  It would be a bit nicer if the data you wanted to sort upon lived in its own legitimate field in the table.

Comment: ok thanks. i was thinking about creating a private mysql function that would explode the string but substring seems to do the trick.